# find maximum and minimum of : $\tan (a)\tan (b)\tan (c)$

Tags: inequality, optimization, jensen-inequality, tangent-line-method

find maximum of :

$1)$ $\tan (a)\tan (b)\tan (c)$

where :   $a+b+c=\frac{π}{3}$

$a,b,c\in [0,\frac{π}{3}[$

and minimum of :

$2)$ $\tan (a)\tan (b)\tan (c)$

if :  $a+b+c=2\frac{π}{3}$  , $a,b,c\in [\frac{π}{3},\frac{π}{2}[$

my attempt for maximum :

drap $f(x)=\tan x$ then $f"(x)=2\sec^{3} x\sin x>0$ 
so $f$ is convex function by Jensen inequality we obtaine :

$\tan a\tan b\tan c≤(\frac{\tan a\tan b\tan c}{3})^{3}$

$≤\frac{f(\frac{a+b+c}{3})}{9}$

$≤\frac{\tan \frac{π}{9}}{9}$

is my work correct ?

and what about  of minimum ?

If any one have another ideas let we see!

Comment: For the minimum, I doubt that the conditions are $a+b+c=\frac{2\pi}3$ and $a,b,c\in[\pi/3,\pi/2[$. There is no such $(a,b,c)$ as the lower bound implies $a+b+c\geq\pi$.

Comment: @Ellen Ellen Jensen's inequality states that $f(a)+f(b)+f(c) \ge 3f \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)$ for a convex function. So you have to consider the function $f(x)=\ln(\tan x)$, not $f(x)=\tan x$.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your problem to a problem in two variables:
$$f(a,b)=\tan(a)\tan(b)\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-a-b\right)$$
and computing the partial derivaties.
$$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a}=\sec ^2(a) \tan (b) \cot \left(a+b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)-\tan (a) \tan (b) \csc
   ^2\left(a+b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial b}=\tan (a) \sec ^2(b) \cot \left(a+b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)-\tan (a) \tan (b) \csc
   ^2\left(a+b+\frac{\pi }{6}\right)$$

Comment: Can you complete this idea ?

Comment: Sorry for that, just corrected!

Answer (score 1):

For second, you can use $f(x)=\ln(\tan(x))$ and $f''(x)=\dfrac{\tan^4(x)-1}{\tan^2(x)}\ge0$ for  $x\in [\frac{π}{3},\frac{π}{2}]$ and $x=2\pi/3$

Comment: thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

1. For $a=b=c=\frac{\pi}{9}$ we obtain a value $\tan^3\frac{\pi}{9}.$

We'll prove that it's a maximal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\ln\tan{a}\leq3\ln\tan\frac{\pi}{9},$$ which is true because
$$3\ln\tan\frac{\pi}{9}-\sum_{cyc}\ln\tan{a}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\ln\tan\frac{\pi}{9}-\ln\tan{a}+\frac{2}{\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}\left(a-\frac{\pi}{9}\right)\right)\geq0.$$
Let $f(a)=\ln\tan\frac{\pi}{9}-\ln\tan{a}+\frac{2}{\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}\left(a-\frac{\pi}{9}\right).$

Thus, $$f'(a)=-\frac{1}{\sin{a}\cos{a}}+\frac{2}{\sin\frac{2\pi}{9}}=\frac{2(\sin2a-\sin40^{\circ})}{\sin2a\sin40^{\circ}},$$
which gives $a_{min}=20^{\circ}$ and $f(a)\geq f(20^{\circ})=0.$

Comment: thank you very much , few explain in last step $\sin$ ??

Comment: @Ellen Ellen I added something. See now.